# How to copy word field to clipboard

Tags: c#, ms-word, field, clipboard

Using C#, could you tell me please what to copy to the clipboard to let Word recognize it as a field, like this:

```
«SomeText»
```

after toggle field code

```
{ MERGEFIELD SomeText \* MERGEFORMAT }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML format... Using some kind of clipboard viewer the exact format can be find out easily.